# Software to calculate AIC for Power law, Exponential, and Exponentially truncated power law

Tags: statistics

I am trying to fit the log-log plot of the cumulative distribution of
a network to one of three models: Exponential `(P(k)~e^(-ak))`,
Exponentially truncated power law `(P(k)~k^(a-1)e^(k/kc))`, and Power
law `(P(k)~k^-a)`. I know this is a low-information test, but I am
simply trying to determine which of the three models is the best fit
(or possibly the least terrible fit!)

I have in an Excel Sheet with the `logCPK` (Column B) of the network and
the fitted values for the three models (Columns C, D, and E). I have
also calculated the Total Sum of Squares (SST) (Column F), and then
the Sum Squares for Error (SSE) for the three models (Columns G, H,
and I).

For each of the three models, I then calculated `1-(sum(SSE)/sum(SST))`
to estimate the R^2 value of a simple linear regression for each of
the models, which is highlighted in yellow at the bottom of the Excel
Sheet. So, now I have three R^2 values (Power law= 0.507 , Exponential
= 0.777, Exponentially truncated power law =0.899).

At first, it seems the Exponentially truncated power law has the best
fit (highest R^2 value). However, I am unsure how to account for
penalizing the fact that the Exponentially truncated power law has
degrees of freedom of 2, while the other two models have degrees of
freedom of 1.

When I contacted another statistics online source, I was told I should
use the "likelihood ratio test". From what I understand of this, the
best fit will have the least negative value for its "log likelihood".
However, the Exponentially truncated power law will appear to have the
least negative value for its "log likelihood" at first (as it has two
df, and the other two models only have one df), and so I must test
whether it truly remains less negative after accounting for the
degrees of freedom.

I *think* I know how to theoretically calculate *part of* that in Excel:

1) Use chidist(A,B) where A is

```
2*(log.likelihood of Exponentially
truncated - log.likelihood of Power law)
```

and B is the difference in df
(2-1=1). If the p-value is less than 0.05, then  the Exponentially
truncated really was significantly better fit than Power law.
2) Use chidist(A,B) where A is

```
2*(log.likelihood of Exponentially
truncated - log.likelihood of Exponential)
```

and B is the difference in
df (2-1=1). If the p-value is less than 0.05, then the Exponentially
truncated really was a bitter fit than Exponential.

Then I could conclude which of the models is the best fit.

And this is where my question is (depending on whether my thinking
above is correct), how does one go about calculating the
log(likelihood)? I have searched, but am still at a lost. It seems
that this calculation by hand is a beast (unless I can simply use
what I already have in Excel), and so I am asking about software as well.

The other alternative is to calculate AIC (also suggested to me), although
I believe I would still have the same problem, where I need to calculate
the log(likelihood) for the AIC equation `(AIC = 2k - 2ln(L))`.

So my specific question is how can I calculate AIC and/or log(likelihood)
for the three models either directly from what I have in Excel or using
software.

Thank you in advance!

PS: I have looked into R programming and see it has an AI{stats} and
logLik{stats} function, but I do not understand from the documentation
whether I have all the necessary input information to run these functions,
and if so, how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

For power-laws you can use the formulae and guidelines given by:

```
Newman MEJ (2005) Power laws, Pareto distributions and Zipf’s law. 
Contemporary Physics   46: 323–351. doi:10.1080/00107510500052444.
```

or also

```
Xiao X, White E, Hooten M, Durham S (2011) On the use of log-transformation vs. 
nonlinear regression for analyzing biological power-laws. Ecology 92: 1887–1894.
doi:10.1890/11-0538.1.
```

they have an online appendix with the code in R

And after that you will have a beter idea of how to do it with the other distributions.